# Datasheet of ECS-2200B 10 MHz oscillator

Tags: oscillator, datasheet

I have problem finding information about this oscillator. I can't find what is the activation time when the control pin 1 is put HIGH. In the datasheet the only thing I found is start up time which is maximum 10 ms, but I suppose it refers to VCC.

This is the datasheet: https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ecs-2200x.pdf

Comment: You can't find it in the data sheet because it's not there. But you don't ask a question about it. For what purpose you need the info?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find what is the activation time when the control pin 1 is put
> HIGH.

I infer from data sheet that the oscillator itself is *always oscillating* after power-up. The only way to stop internal oscillation is likely to reduce +Vdd toward zero. I believe this because no conditions are present for its Idd specification of 17mA...

So *start-up time* most likely refers to time from powering-up Vdd to +5V. Crystal oscillators often require milliseconds to reach full amplitude from power-up. The tri-state function of pin #1 is not specified, but is likely very quick (much, much faster than start-up time).

Since the internal pull-up resistor value is not given, activation-time when pin #1 goes high may depend on how it is driven:

- if driven from a logic type of open-collector or open-drain, activation time may be some microseconds. De-activation (going low) would likely be faster.
- if driven from a standard logic type of active pull-up/pull-down totem pole, activation time would likely be commensurate with rise/fall time of that logic family.

That "data sheet" is pretty sketchy. If ECS has no other application literature, then contact them.